# django exclude fields in dictionary that are not model attributes

Tags: python, django, django-models

I have a HTML form with a number of form elements, that gets posted to the server on submit.
In the back-end ,once the validation is passed, I am trying to pass the whole POST dictionary to the model and save it. like this:

```
self.form_data = {key:value for key,value in self.request.POST.iteritems() }
ApplicationModel(**self.form_data).save()
```

However, there are a few extra items in the form that has no associated attribute in the model. So I end up in an error saying,

```
'csrf_token' is an invalid keyword argument for this function
```

I have to explicitly remove these items from the form dictionary before passing to the model.

Is there a way to suppress this error & ignore all items in the dictionary that does'nt have a mapping to the model  attribute?

Comment: I dont think this is a good idea. It is one way of being explicit - Send only the info the model absolutely needs

Comment: @karthikr Its alwasy the csrf_token that i have to remove from every form object. Still I am curious how would one solve this problem?

Comment: `{key:value for key,value in self.request.POST.iteritems() if key not in ('csrf_token', )}`

Comment: @karthikr that is what I am using now, I was thinking of removing this line & silencing it using some model manager

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a [`ModelForm`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/modelforms/#modelform) for your model, and let it handle that logic.

This is what `ModelForm`'s are for, and this is how you're supposed to be solving that problem:

```
# forms.py
from django.forms import ModelForm
from myapp.models import Article


class ApplicationForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Application


# views.py

def my_view(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = ApplicationForm(request.POSt)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            return HttpResponseRedirect("/thanks/")
    form = ApplicationForm()
    return render(request, 'template.html', {'form': form})
```